# Why I have visitor hourly from San Francisco Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Google Analytics shows I have a hourly visit (exactly on 1:00 and 2:00 and ... ) from San Francisco. Anyone knows what is this? Is this a robot? If yes what kind of robot is it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To provide you with an answer, community will need some more data.

1. Please show report screenshot where you see that somebody from SF comes to your site every hour.
2. Depending on what you provide for p. 1, some more information may be needed to answer your question.